# Need a solution for a solution (Subsurf Pinching)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

So I've recently viewed this video to solve my pinching issues with a car bumper:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rlMzsBWtPY

However, how would one get the bumper lights and stuff back on the bumper once you're done with the shrink wrap and stuff?

For example, my model has fog lamps on the bumper. I've removed it and I'm left with only the cut-out hole. I then use the guide mesh to fix it. Now how do I get the fog lamp back on it WITHOUT applying the modifiers?

The only way I can think of is by applying all the modifiers first which is both frustrating to work with and removes all the flexibility I can have with the model.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: what do you mean? If you want to add stuff, create new objects... if you want to use some parts of the bumper topology, duplicate your bumper, apply the modifiers and use the topology of the applied version, but keep a non-applied version

Comment: For example, my model has fog lamps on the bumper. I've removed it and I'm left with only the cut-out hole. I then use the guide mesh to fix it. Now how do I get the fog lamp back on it WITHOUT applying the modifiers? Since the Shrinkwrap will just flatten the fog lamp mesh with to the bumper itself

Comment: I've added this example to the question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this was a stupid question. He says in the video to use vertex groups so I just assigned the detailing to a vertex group and the shrinkwrap modifier now ignores it which gives me the desired effect.